# Trying to make Qt HUD in OSG, camera issue

Tags: qt, interface, openscenegraph, hud

I'm kind of newbie in both OSG and Qt, still I'm trying to make Qt HUD upon my OSG window, what I want is Qt interface elements fixed inside OSG scene, not spinning with the model. The thing is, I need Qt elements INSIDE osg scene, not OSG scene inside Qt window (like in OSGviewerQt example).

What I've got yet is OSGQtWidgets example with --useWidgetImage --fullscreen arguments, which shows fixed Qt controls ontop of OSG Model. The thing is, it creates new (FIXED) camera for qt element ontop of OSG model -- because of that, user cannot spin and move OSG model because camera is not transparent.

So the question is: is there a way to make transparent camera with useable Qt elements in it? Or is there some other way to achieve my goals?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, if you want a HUD, why would you want Qt 'elements' (like what?) _inside_ the OSG scene?  Surely you want them laid over the top, oblivious to camera data.

Comment: thanks for quick reply; needed Qt elements -- buttons, tree-views etc; I want them _inside_ OSG scene because there is OSGWidget interface at this moment in the project I'm working with, and it would be nice to change it from OSGWidget to Qt; therefore, it seems much easier to change to Qt controls _inside_ scene, when using something as in OSGViewerQt example would be like writing completely new ui

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to try this out for myself first, but you can try setting a property on the Orthogonal "HUD" camera to let events pass through to the regular OSG viewer:

```
camera->setAllowEventFocus(false);
```

If you're using a recent version of osgQtWidgets.cpp, you'd want to add this around line 414.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didnt work out. Though even if it did, my Qt control would become unclickable, wouldnt it?